# JSON request is not returning data

Tags: json, swift

I'm trying to create a weather application. I followed a tutorial about JSON and Swift 4 Decodable, I followed the tutorial and it worked. The problem is that when I'm trying to put my own URL to make a request, it won't work.
This is my code:

```
class MainVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    let jsonUrlString: String = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/APIKEY/37.8267,-122.4233"

    private func getForecast(){
        guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do{
                let weatherForecast = try JSONDecoder().decode(Weather.self, from: data)
                print(weatherForecast)
            }catch _ as NSError{

            }
            }.resume()
    }
}
```

Error Log:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4864 "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead." UserInfo={NSCodingPath=(
), NSDebugDescription=Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.}
```

How can I parse this https://darksky.net/dev/docs#forecast-request ? I only need the few things from the Daily sections but It seems like an array inside an array to me.

Comment: Could you log the errors and share those? (`err` in the data task response block and the error you are now ignoring in the catch block)

Comment: I don't get any errors :\

Comment: If you don't get any errors, then what is printed when you print `weatherForecast`?

Comment: Dont you need to update 'APIKEY' in your url with an actual apikey? 
Like: private let apiKey = "your api key here".

Then:
let jsonUrlString: String = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/\(apiKey)/37.8267,-122.4233"

Comment: @silicon_valley nothing is printed, I guess there is something with the Json, should I only need few things from the Json request (day, and temp) for now, maybe this is the problem?

Comment: @emrepun Yes, I need an actual key, which I have.

Comment: Change your do-catch block to this, then look at the json error you are getting. `do {
            let weatherForecast = try JSONDecoder().decode(Weather.self, from: data)
            print(weatherForecast)
        } catch let jsonError as NSError {
            print(jsonError)
        }`

Comment: I'm adding the output to the OP

Comment: Thanks, can you also add your `Weather` struct?

Comment: @silicon_valley Don't cast a decoding error to `NSError`, never do that. Just simply write `... catch { print(error) }`

Comment: Fair point. I was just copying the code @JohnDoah had already written (which was casting it to NSError)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your Weather struct is built up incorrectly. It should looks something like this:

```
struct DataItem: Codable {
    var summary: String
    var uvIndex: Int    
}

struct Info: Codable {
    var summary: String
    var icon: String
    var data: [DataItem]
}

struct Weather: Codable {
    var daily: Info
    var hourly: Info
    var timezone: String
}
```

I've left quite a few items out, but this should help you to get started.

Comment: Thanks, I had something exactly like that, but it still didn't work. Well I will test this again tomorrow and try to fix it. Will update of course. Thanks again!

Comment: Could you please add your code, otherwise we can't help... The problem is in the JSON deserialisation, so that's the code we need to see to know what is wrong with it.

Comment: Sorry took me so long to answer, this was the problem, I did had just one struct so I guess it only took the first item from the JSON. Anyway, Thanks again!